# How to know that the device's screen is bigger?

Tags: mobile, java-me, screen, lwuit

When the phone's screen is not very big, like an Alcatel OT-806D's screen, then label text can be seen with a plain, small, proportional font with a size of 9. But when the screen is like HTC's screen then the label's text cannot be read with that font! How can I tell if a screen is "big"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code.

```
int screen_width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
int screen_height = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
```

Its returns the mobile screen width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Display dis = Display.getDisplay(this);
 Displayable d = dis.getCurrent();
 int width = d.getWidth();
 int height = d.getHeight();
```